# how to use common less variable with styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Say I have a styled component, in index.jsx

```
import './index.less';
class Input extends React.Component {
   ...
}
```

and my index.less files looks:

```
.input{
   color: @whiteColor;
}
```

This index.less has to work with the mixin.less that imported in the root project.

So my question is, even though I imported the mixin.less, it prompts variable @whiteColor not found. Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

I have felt the same pain, why isn't my styled component resolving less variables?
The syntax is simple JavaScript, just do:

```
.input{
   color: ${props => props.whiteColor};
   // or
   color: ${props => props.theme.whiteColor};
}
```

But, at my company, we had thousands of less components, and we really thought that the less syntax was cleaner and definitely faster to write. We developed [Styless](https://github.com/jean343/styless).

It is a babel plugin that parses less and generates javascript code. Add it to your .babelrc file.

```
{
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-styless"]
}
```

Then, we can do!!

```
const Input = styled.input`
    @highlight: blue;                           // can be overwritten by theme or props
    background: darken(@highlight, 5%);         // make green darken by 5%
`;
```

Check [here](https://github.com/jean343/styless/blob/master/docs/receipe-theme.md) to see how to use the theme provider and load variable from your `index.less`!

Answer (score 0):

You can try import the mixin.less in index.less

Comment: that's  not what i m aiming for, I dont want to import mixin.less in every component

Comment: Maybe you can config your webpack config, add the mixin.less to entry.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying the same than you.

But then I thought.. it is that what I really want?  Because styled-components propose a different approach to having a modular structure for your styles.

https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced Check theming, is amazing powerful.
Because in styled components you define the variables with javascript.

And if you want color manipulation like less, sass, you can check https://github.com/erikras/styled-components-theme

Its like forgetting about less, and sass and moving it to a new style modules.

Still, if you want to keep your defined style classes, you can do that:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Attach the passed-in className to the DOM node
    return <div className={`some-global-class ${this.props.className}`} />;
  }
}
```

Check the existing CSS usage from docs: 
https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#existing-css